# Derivators (in English)

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory

Grothendieck, before he disappeared, was working on a manuscript called "Les Derivateurs", which detailed the theory of derivators.  Prof. Cisinski has done work with them as he mentioned in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17425/homotopy-limits-over-fibered-categories/17463#17463).  However, most of his work is in French, and I was wondering if there are any typed up references in english (the nLab has written notes from a seminar, but that's it).  I intend to read the references in French later, but could someone explain or give a reference that explains in English the definition of a derivator and the motivation for them?

Comment: According to Wikipedia the original idea was developed in Pursuing Stacks which is in English as far as I know.

Comment: FWIW, [the French original has been LaTeXed](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/groth/Derivateursengl.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a few references in English, there are the papers of Heller, the main one being:

A. Heller, Homotopy theories, Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 71 (383) (1988)

There is also a paper I wrote with A. Neeman, in which there is a little introduction to derivators in the second half of:
Additivity for derivator K-theory, Adv. Math. 217 (2008), no. 4, 1381-1475

One can see derivators in action in the work of G. Tabuada (he explains Bousfield localization and stabilization in this setting, and compares with the model category point of view):
Higher K-theory via universal invariants, Duke Math. J. 145 (2008), no. 1, 121–206
(availabe as arXiv:0706.2420).

Answer (score 10):

George Maltsiniotis has given a mini-course in Seville last year, they include some handwritten notes in English, which are the part 3 of the course:

[Lecture_III_Derivators.pdf](http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~maltsin/Seville/Lecture_III_Derivators.pdf)

For the other parts of the course notes see the conference [page](http://congreso.us.es/htag09/php/index.php?carga=courses).

Answer (score 9):

Some very brief remarks on derivateurs are in Bertrand Toen's habilitation thesis on pages 12-14 and 27-29, available [here](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~toen/note.html). They mainly emphasize how derivateurs are sort of a 2-truncated homotopy theory of homotopy theories - nothing to learn derivateur-language from, but maybe a nice addition to the general picture.

Answer (score 9):

My recommendation would be [Moritz Groth](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/)'s excellent notes

- [Derivators, pointed derivators, and stable derivators](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/groth_derivators.pdf).

He also has a follow-up paper on

- [Monoidal and Enriched derivators](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/groth_monoidal.pdf)

as well as a

- [A short course on infinity-categories](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/InfinityCategories.pdf).

These are great introductions to all of these topics.

Answer (score 6):

Urs Schreiber updated the [nLab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivator) 40 minutes or so ago with an explanation from Prof. Cisinski.

Answer (score 5):

M Groth's [book project: The theory of Derivators](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/monos.htmpl) is a highly recommendable reading!

They are two volumes, the [volume I](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/monos/intro-to-der-1.pdf) is available as a draft version.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

A theory of a very similar flavour can be found in a [preprint](http://www.mathematik.uni-osnabrueck.de/K-theory/0139/Adams.pdf) of Jens Franke.

Comment: Dead link is dead. :(

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.170.3817&rep=rep1&type=pdf should work. Notice that this is only part 1 of the preprint while part 2 seems to contain a gap, which is partially filled by a recent preprint of Irakli Patchkoria. 

Comment: Irakli Patchkoria's preprint: http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6309

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try Grothendieck himself

T. Hosgood has translated a letter from Grothendieck to R. Thomason where he gave the motivation for the theory

https://labs.thosgood.com/translations/grothendieck-thomason-91-04-02.html

Maybe you can find it useful!